# Which environment variable to use on Heroku for services that only listen to https

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, heroku

I'm setting up an https only web API service using AspNet core which is to be deployed on Heroku. The deployment is done via docker, so I have a Dockerfile configured. But I'm getting an error relating to the https port binding whenever I deploy to Heroku. I want to know if Heroku provides a special env variable for https where a service can bind to specify the https port the service should listen to.

AspNet core provides 2 environment variables `ASPNETCORE_HTTPS_PORT=5001` and `ASPNETCORE_URLS=https://*:5001` where one can specify the https port the service should listen to.

But since Heroku does not allow a web process to manually specify the port it should listen to, they provide a PORT env variable the web app can bind to.

I've tried using `ASPNETCORE_HTTPS_PORT=$PORT` and `ASPNETCORE_URLS=https://*:$PORT`, but I'm getting the following errors:

```
crit: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[0]
Unable to start Kestrel.
System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (13): Permission denied at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.UpdateStatusAfterSocketErrorAndThrowException(SocketError error, String callerName) 
at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoBind(EndPoint endPointSnapshot, SocketAddress socketAddress)
at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Bind(EndPoint localEP)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Sockets.SocketConnectionListener.Bind()
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Sockets.SocketTransportFactory.BindAsync(EndPoint endpoint, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.KestrelServer.<>c__DisplayClass21_0`1.<<StartAsync>g__OnBind|0>d.MoveNext()
```

Comment: "I want to know if Heroku provides a special env variable for https where a service can bind to specify the https port the service should listen to."—it does not. I don't know about those specific .NET Core variables, but as far as Heroku is concerned there is only `PORT`. And this _should_ work. Would you please share the relevant part of your `Dockerfile`?

Comment: I doubt whether your  environment variables is passed correctly. Because it works fine for me  with ASP.NET Core. It only occurs when I specify/pass these settings in a wrong way.

Comment: Now that I think about it, Heroku doesn't generally expect your application to have HTTPS built-in. That's something that can be added, e.g. via ACM or a custom certificate. Are you literally running an HTTPS server with an arbitrary certificate inside your Docker container?

Comment: @Chris thanks for the clarification. I was able to fix this now. I'm using ACM but my app was previously trying to listen on http and https ports while redirecting the http requests to https; then I switched to https alone when I discovered heroku only supports PORT var. But now that I know [heroku uses a load balancer](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/http-routing#routing) to proxy https requests over http, I was able to configure my app the proper way.  I will be posting my solution to this shortly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So I was able to resolve the issue after going through Heroku's documentation (extensively). Here are the key findings relating to this problem:

1. [Heroku uses a load balancer](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/http-routing#routing) which proxies all its request.
2. Heroku terminates any SSL communication from your app, so all requests are forwarded to your app over http; your clients' https requests are proxied over http.
3. Since the requests are proxied, Heroku [passes Forwarded headers](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/http-routing#heroku-headers) for the originating request.
4. Your app can only receive requests and [should only listen to the PORT](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#web-dynos) env variable.

Now that i have the in mind, I was able to configure my app correctly.

Listening on http not https: `ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://*:$PORT`

Using FowardedHeaders and Rewriter middlewares in AspNet core middleware pipeline:

```
var forwardedHeadersOptions = new ForwardedHeadersOptions {
    ForwardedHeaders = ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedFor | ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto
};
forwardedHeadersOptions.KnownNetworks.Clear();
forwardedHeadersOptions.KnownProxies.Clear();
app.UseForwardedHeaders(forwardedHeadersOptions);

var rewriteOptions = new RewriteOptions ().AddRedirectToHttps(308);
app.UseRewriter(rewriteOptions);
...
```

The ForwardedHHeaders middleware [maps the Forwarded headers to HttpContext.Request](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/proxy-load-balancer?view=aspnetcore-2.2#other-proxy-server-and-load-balancer-scenarios). And the Rewriter middleware [will redirect http request scheme to https](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/url-rewriting?view=aspnetcore-2.2).